# Continuous Video Wallpaper throughout multiple HTML Files

Tags: html, loops, video, wallpaper, continuous

I am making an HTML website and I am a bit lost now. I have created a video wallpaper. But what I am confuse right now as to how do I make my video in a continuous video and not start from the beginning each time I click onto a new page? I wish I could upload a video to show you what I'm talking about, but instead, I'm just going to put a link to my video which I just posted on YouTube just now to make it easier for you guys to understand.

[Video Wallpaper HTML](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJXY9-ORgjU)

Also I would like to have it play in a continuous format no matter how many times you navigate through the website and then it starts over again in a loop.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: you'll want to track the currentTime when transitioning off a page, then reload the video on the next page, set the currentTime, and then play...

Comment: Can you give me an example of a code for that? Where and what to place it in my HTML and CSS? Or a YouTube video showing an example of that? Any tips would be grateful!

Comment: another option would be to have the links simply use javascript to replace the content div on the same page (possibly easier than tracking the position in the video, and would make the experience smoother)

Comment: @Offbeatmammal do you have an example code if you could find one? Any info whether is from another coding example site or a youtube video that describes that kind of coding would be greatly appreciated. Sorry I'm more of a visual/kinesetic learner.